# Close tag on closing brace using Html Helper in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html-helper

How can I create a helper like the Html.Form helper, which closes the tag when you close the braces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs to implement `IDisposable` and render the closing brace in the `Dispose` method.  You can then have the same `using` behavior as with the HtmlForm helper.

Comment: How can I render my end tag? since I wont be just returning a string anymore, do I have to write in to the response directly?

Comment: Yeah, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435898/create-extension-method-to-produce-open-closing-tags-like-html-beginform