# How can I define asp.net Htmlhelper extensions for derived classes of an abstract base class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In other words I want to do the following:

```
public abstract class Shape {
    public virtual RenderHTML();
}

public class Circle : Shape {
    public override RenderHTML() {}
}  

public class Square : Shape {
    public override RenderHTML() {}
}

public class MyViewModel {
    public Shape shape;
}

// single call to render HTML for whatever shape is needed
// should call on render method for Circle or Square depending on type of Shape
@Html.RenderShape(Model.shape)
```

How should I do this?
I somehow need to pass the instance into the HTML helper.

EDIT: found a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2413006/2259509)

Comment: You should define abstract method (i.e. `Render()`) in your `Shape` class and override it in the concrete subclasses. See similar example for more details: [Polymorphism (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx)

Comment: I understand that I can override render on derived classes from a base class, the part I couldn't figure out was how to define an HTMLHelper that enabled this automatically, I'll update the question to make this clearer. I was looking for a solution that somehow passed in the type into the HTML helper method itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very basic implementation of how you can achieve something like this:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString RenderShape(this HtmlHelper helper,
        Shape shape)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(shape.RenderHtml());
    }
}
```

where `RenderHtml()` would return a string with unencoded HTML.

Comment: awesome, thanks! what does the call to the helper look like from a razor view? would it just be @Html.RenderShape<Shape>(Model.shape)?

Comment: @SandeepPhadke Not sure why I made that generic, but I've fixed that now.  Anyway, `@Html.RenderShape(Model.Shape)` is all you need.